# Rails Route Helper Methods included into Service Object not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted to make my route helpers available in my service object.

Ex:

```
blog_path(blog) #make available in service object
```

The issue is that I am using passenger, so the application is *relative* to the domain.

Ex: Instead of the path loading: `www.my_domain.com/blog/1`, passenger loads the path with: `www.my_domain.com/this_app/blog/1`.

Currently my route helper in my service object is rendering the first version and not the second version.

Here is what my service object looks like:

```
class BuildLink
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
  RouteHelpers = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  attr_accessor :blog

  def initialize(blog)
    @blog = blog
  end

  def init
    content_tag(:li, link_to(“Show Blog“, RouteHelpers.blog_path(blog)))
  end
end
```

The route works locally because on localhost I do not have a relative path. But when I put it in production it does not work because passenger is expecting the application name as the relative path, but the service object is not including the application name within the url it generates.

That relative path works everywhere else in my application, it just doesn't properly generate the relative path within the service object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that actionview-related methods are not available to POROs.

In order to get all the great stuff from actionview: you need to utilize the `view_context` keyword.  Then: you can simply call upon actionview-related methods from your `view_context`:

```
class BuildLink
  attr_accessor :blog, :view_context

  def initialize(blog, view_context)
    @blog = blog
    @view_context = view_context
  end

  def init
    content_tag(:li, link_to(“Show Blog“, view_context.blog_path(blog)))
  end
end
```

So for example: from your controller you would call upon this PORO like so:

```
BuildLink.new(@blog, view_context).init
```

For more information, see below references:

- [Rails doc on view_context](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Rendering.html#method-i-view_context)
- Utilization of `view_context` via presenter pattern, shown in [this article](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-presenters/)
- [Railscast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHsq6aFlP0U) which talks through utilizing `view_context` via presenter pattern